# RemoveRegistryKey not removing registry keys

Tags: windows, wix, registry, wix3.5, wix3.7

I have a set of registry values that were set by a previous version of my application. It was set permanently (from c++ code) and will not be removed when the application is uninstalled. Now I am trying to edit the wix installation file to remove those registry keys on new installation of the application but it is not working. Here is my code -

```
<Component Id="RemoveOldRegKeys" Guid="9xxxxxx" KeyPath="yes">
<RemoveRegistryKey Id="RemoveAppInit64" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs" Action="removeOnInstall"/> 
</Component>
```

I have a feature where this component is referred -

```
<Feature Id="SmartCardFeature" Level="1">
<ComponentRef Id="RemoveOldRegKeys" />
</Feature>
```

I checked the install logs and it seems to be executing fine. These are the lines I am getting -

```
MSI (s) (A8:44) [14:00:43:435]: Executing op: RegOpenKey(Root=-2147483646,Key=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs,,BinaryType=1,,)
MSI (s) (A8:44) [14:00:43:435]: Executing op: RegRemoveKey()
MSI (s) (A8:44) [14:00:43:436]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs 3: 2
```

I am just wondering if what I am doing is possible and if yes, what am I missing or doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppInit_DLLs` is a value (under the `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows` key), not a key itself. You want `RemoveRegistryValue` instead.